# Informatica error Severity Timestamp Node Thread Message Code Message ERROR READER_1_1_1 RR_4036 Error connecting to database

Tags: oracle, informatica

I have created an Oracle wire protocol 7.1 connection to Oracle database.  With a network test connection it succeeds and I am able to view data while previewing imported table in source analyzer. I also created a connection in workflow manager but when executing workflow the following error occurs.

```
Severity    Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code    Message
ERROR   7/22/2017 12:51:53 PM   node01_asus READER_1_1_1    RR_4036 Error connecting to database [
Database driver error...
Function Name : Logon
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Database driver error...
Function Name : Connect
Database Error: Failed to connect to database using user [username] and connection string [ORCL].].
```

Comment: sir if credential are wrong then how it is previewing  data in source analyser.i am using same credentials whice used to import table in SA.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Informatica Power center..
The error itself is self explanatory..
The connection for session/workflow is created from Workflow manager--> connections and this has nothing to do with Source Analyzer connection that you have created. Below possible  reasons   The error

1. WF Might be using incorrect parameter name
2. WF is using wrong parameters
3. As the message clearlysays wrong credentials..

Answer (score 0):

Informatica doesn't use the same database connection by default as you used to define the source. In the session task, open the mappings tab and check which relational connection it is using